# oracle sql query requirements

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some data in oracle table abot 10,000 rows i want to genrate column which return 1 for ist row and 2 for second and so on 1 for 3rd and 2 for 4th and 1 for 5th and 2 for 6th and so on..Is there any way that i can do it using sql query or any script which can update my column like this.that it will generate 1,2 as i mentioned above i have thought much but i didn't got to do this using sql or any other scencrio for my requirements.plz help if any possibility for doing this with my table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the combination of the `ROWNUM` and `MOD` functions.

Your query would look something like this:

`SELECT ROWNUM, 2 - MOD(ROWNUM, 2) FROM ...`

The [`MOD` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm) will return 0 for even rows and 1 for odd rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
select mod(rownum,5)+1,fld1, fld2, fld3 from mytable;
```

Edit: 
I did not misunderstand requirements, I worked around them. Adding a column and then  updating a table that way is a bad design idea. Tables are seldom completely static, even rule and validation tables. The only time this might make any sense is if the table is locked against delete, insert, and update.  Any change to any existing row can alter the logical order. Which was never specified. Delete means the entire sequence has to be rewritten.  Update and insert can have the same effect.

And if you wanted to do this you can use a sequence to insert a bogus counter.  A sequence that cycles over and over, assuming you know the order and can control inserts and updates in terms of that order.

Comment: You misunderstood OP's requirements.